# how to grep the content of txt file

Tags: unix, grep

I have 2 txt files

file 1

```
vol12 ,cs_rvl      
vol12 ,cvs_rvl     
vol12 ,svn_rvl     
vol12 ,swarch      
abc_xyz ,abc_xyz 

def6g ,def6g  
vmfs_unix ,vmfs_unix

vol5 ,images

vol4 ,svn_blr

vol4 ,home4
```

file 2

```
svn_rvl     
swarch 

vmfs_unix

home4
```

My file 2 is an processed output, which has only qtree name is it possible to get the the content of file2

Eg: for `svn_rvl` it should display `vol12/svn_rvl`

```
swarch -- vol12/swarch
vmfs_unix -- vmfs_unix/vmfs_unix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}($2 in a){print $2" -- "$1"/"$2}' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
test1.txt is your file1 and test2.txt is your file2 and results.txt will have the output in a file stored in the same folder

```
openvas:~/test${ while read myline;do recset=`echo $myline`; var=$(grep $recset test1.txt);  echo $var >> results.txt ;  done } < test2.txt
openvas:~/test$ more results.txt 
vol12 ,svn_rvl
vol12 ,swarch
vmfs_unix ,vmfs_unix
vol4 ,home4
```

or

```
openvas:~/test$ `{ while read myline;do recset=`echo $myline`; var=$(grep $recset test1.txt);  echo $myline '--' $var >> results.txt ;  done } < test2.txt`
openvas:~/test$ more results.txt 
svn_rvl -- vol12 ,svn_rvl
swarch -- vol12 ,swarch
vmfs_unix -- vmfs_unix ,vmfs_unix
home4 -- vol4 ,home4
```